# Is there a common approach to encrypting data at the database level?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, encryption, standard-edition

Is there a common approach to encrypting data at the database level?  The application I am working on will be storing sensitive data that only users of the system themselves will be able to view.

Comment: Following on from Jon's comment, are you suggesting that each user has a different encryption key? Are you actually asking about row level security a.k.a filtering to the rows a user can see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your security restrictions you could:

- use [cell-level encryption](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179331.aspx) (basically column-level encryption), which decrypts the data once it hits the buffer pool; it's available in all SQL Server versions, including Express
- encrypt/decrypt data in your own application, so unencrypted data is never present in the database server's memory